# Resolve: Client <XYZ> is configured for secret but secret was not received

Tags: next.js, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I am trying to integrate my AWS Cognito userPool into my Netxjs application, and when I configure its values ​​and try to make a request, I get this error. How can I solve that? Is it true that the userPool should not have generating client secret active? Thank you

If I generate a userpool directly from the console with amplify, this works for me, the problem is when trying to connect an existing userpool, which I have configured in the backend.